# Can EF Code First populate entities from a dataset?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dataset, ef-code-first

I have the ability to query a legacy system that returns a .NET DataSet.

Is there a way to use the Entity Framework Code First to populate my C# entities directly from a DataSet instead of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course copy the records yourself, but that would still leave the issues of tracking and updating.

So I would say No. Unless somebody develops an EF Provider (IQueryable) for Datasets. And that would be a lot of work, including running (E)SQL on datasets.

Comment: You can import them into a list, probably even into the EF EntitySet collection. But you're not going to get much benefit from EF, so why bother? Just think `List<MyClass>`

Answer (score 0):

You could just instantiate the entities (manually, with Automapper, whatever) and then `Attach` them to the DbSet.